# Javascript function to get values from C# fields or properties in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I’m new to JavaScript. Basically I want a function in JavaScript which will show me an email preview in a web browser. I’ve stored email’s template, body and contents.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT Name, template, body, contents FROM Email
WHERE EmailID = 1
```

**C#:**
  I have a LinkButton (ID="lnkViewDoc") on asp.net page and the code behind is:

```
lnkViewDoc.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return preview_email();");
```

**JavaScript:**
I need a function please which will pick values from the class fields and show it in a web browser. thanks

```
function preview_email() {

  ..................
  window.open() //Something
}
```

**Contents:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">     
<head>      
    <title></title>  
</head>  
<body>
  <center>
      ..................
  </center>
</body>
```

**Body:**

```
<div style="text-align: left">   Dear .......,
    ...........................................
</div>  
<div style="text-align: left">   &nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the front-end server tags (bee stings).  The ones I thing you're looking for are

```
<%=... %>
```

This is basically equivalent to `Response.Write()`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a .NET object named "email".
In code behind write:

```
lnkViewDoc.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return preview_email(" + email.EmailID + ");");
```

In javascript:

```
function preview_email(emailid) {

  ..................
  window.open("previewEmail.aspx?emailid=" + emailid, ... more parameters)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of using jquery in your javascript newbie days, you can try to use Jquery Dialog like this:

```
$("<div></div>").load("previewEmail.ascx?emailid=5").dialog({autoOpen:true});
```

or something similar,
you may want to consider just opening that same dialog with a iframe linking to the aspx, because your email will contain disturbing html elements like body tags